# Trouble logging out using passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have a sample node app in which I'm trying to sign-up log-in and log-out users using passport js. I can successfully login and signup users, but when I try to logout users in my terminal I only get the console.log of my deserialize function and it doesn't affect cookies in my browser and also won't log out users since I can retrieve req.user after calling logout function. Here's my passport setup, serialize and deserialize function and also my logout function:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge:60*60*1000} //1hour
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    console.log("serializing user");
    cb(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    console.log("deserializing");
    User.findById(id).then((err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        const userInformation = {
            username: user.email,
        };
        cb(err, user);
    }).catch((err) => {console.error(err)});
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
    console.log("logging out, user:" + req.user);
    req.logout((err) => {
        console.log("inside logout");
        if(err) {
            console.log("error: " + err);
            res.status(500).json({message:"Error logging out"})
        } else{
            console.log("destorying session in logout");
            req.session.destroy(function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("error: " + err);
                    res.status(500).json({message: "Error destroying session"});
                } else{
                    res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
                    res.status(200).json({message: "Logged out successfully"});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your logout route handler. Just remove it `req.logout()` because passport.js doesn't take any argument as per  documentation . So your updated code will look like :

```
app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
    console.log("logging out, user:" + req.user);
    req.logout(); // Remove the callback function 
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("error: " + err);
            res.status(500).json({message: "Error destroying session"});
        } else{
            res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
            res.status(200).json({message: "Logged out successfully"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much @jagroop, I tried your code, but it still returns the user after calling the logout function, and also when I check inspect/Application, it doesn't delete the cookie, And it's odd but when I call logout, it doesn't even return the first console.log line, it only returns something like this (Which seems to be from deserialize function):

deserializing
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6488c796ea90dad63da998f1"),
  username: 'user1',
  password: '$2a$10$t65T9j93RUvQpY.KGWZM4.BC2jJcOBNTgsHoyv6s8ZHT2XE4F9NFG',
  __v: 0
}

Comment: Okay let me check this once.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your logout function might be due to the fact that you are passing a callback function to the req.logout() method. According to the Passport documentation, the req.logout() method does not take any arguments.

You can try removing the callback function from req.logout() and see if that fixes the issue. Here's how your logout function should look like:

```
app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
    console.log("logging out, user:" + req.user);
    req.logout();
    console.log("inside logout");
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("error: " + err);
            res.status(500).json({message: "Error destroying session"});
        } else{
            res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
            res.status(200).json({message: "Logged out successfully"});
        }
    });
});
```

By removing the callback function from req.logout(), the req.user property should be cleared, and the session should be destroyed along with the cookie.

Also, make sure that you have installed the express-session middleware and the passport and passport-local modules in your app. These modules are required for user authentication and session management using Passport.

Comment: Thanks Ali jan, as you see in the other answer I've tried that. Unfortunately, it still doesn't delete the cookie and also returns the user info after calling the logout function.